# Android work with db file from SD card

Tags: android, sql, database, sd-card

I wrote an app which logged data and saved it via SQL into a .db File. I had a method copying it from internal memory to SD card.

Now i wrote a second app, which needs to work with this particular .db file. As i think, that apps can't get access to package files from other apps

(in this case

```
 /data/data/app1_package/databases/my_database.db
```

) 
i need somehow to work with my DB on the SD Card. How do i do that?

Can i use this path in my SQLiteHelper class? Should i copy it from SD to my package, is that even possible (access rights etc.)?

I'm a beginner in databases, some help would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

You can open any readable file path as a database:

```
File dbFile = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myfile.db" );
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbFile,null,null);
```

Note: check if sd-card is mounted before using this code.

Comment: ok, i got 2 classes in my first app. the SQLHelper (which creates the database, and saves it on SD) and SQLDatabase (which performs the SQL instructions).

can i delete the helper class and work with the db file i created like you said? respectively, do i even need the helper class for reading only purposes?

Comment: @Tommy `SQLieHelper` opens database and calls create/upgrade methods. If you can code these two yourself, then yes, you can work without `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Comment: can you give me a hint how i do this? i'm really new in this db stuff

Comment: @Tommy Just checked, You can pass full file path to constructor of `SQLiteOpenHelper` also. `new SQLiteOpenHelper(context,filepath,null,0)`.

Comment: i still dont get it. i tried it without the SQlitehelper but it only gives me nullpointer... if i call SQLiteOpenHelper(context,filepath,null,0) which content belongs in the nwe onCreate/onUpgrade methods?

Answer (score 0):

yes place the DB file in your assets folder and get it this way :

```
     DB_PATH="/data/data/app1_package/databases/my_database.db"
```

in your create :

```
            is = getAssets().open("Meaniningss.db");
            write(is);
```

the method :

```
               public void write(InputStream is) {
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(DB_PATH));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        while ((read = is.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        is.close();
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        System.err.println(out + "\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: the user got my first app, and i write my app independtly from the db file. 
so i need a way to get the db file into my second app after its on the device.

the assets way seems to work that i get the db file WHILE i'm writing the second app. am i seeing this right?